# Finding a saved file on the Simulator?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, core-audio

I'm using the `MusicSequenceFileCreate` function to save out a midi file to make sure the data is correct. I'm not getting any errors but I would like to view the saved file but have no idea how to do this.

I know I can try reading it in in iOS but I would like to view it (and test it) on the desktop.

Is this file stored in some Simulator cache that I can access?

Comment: Errors?  NSError returns (null) if nothing goes wrong.  I'd resolve that before you go any further.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors. I just want to know where the file is saved and if I can access it on the desktop

Comment: Of course, writing an answer as we speak

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes the you can access the Simulator files from `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/`.

In this folder are the various iOS version numbers so pick the one you are running. In that will be `Applications` and you'll see a bunch of GUIDs, one of which will be the running app.

One thing in OSX 10.7 is that the Library folder is now hidden. This article explains how to restore the visibility; [Show User Library Directory in Mac OS X 10.7 Lion](http://osxdaily.com/2011/07/04/show-library-directory-in-mac-os-x-lion/)

Answer (score 58):

The location changed for Xcode 6 with iOS 8:

```
~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/DEVICE_UDID/data/Containers/Data/Application/APPLICATION_ID/Documents
```

`DEVICE_UDID`: can be found out in the Device Inspector (Window -> Devices) and Select the simulated device you're running on. The field `Identifier` contains the device's UDID.
You can also get a list of the simulator UDID's by running the command `xcrun simctl list` (thanks @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia)

`APPLICATION_ID`: I didn't find this number somewhere, so I looked into the folders until I found what I wanted. If someone finds out where this number comes from, let me know.
**EDIT:** The ID of the application changes every time you start the simulator, but when you keep a finder window open pointing to that folder, you'll always find yourself in the correct folder (no idea how they do that; every other application seems to loose track of the files), which is extremely handy!

Comment: You can also get the device UDID by running `xcrun simctl list`

Comment: You can find out the Application ID out by getting the documents folder for your app and printing it to the console: 

`let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager();
let docsDir = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first as? NSURL`



The url shall look like: file:///Users/..../Devices/DEVICE_UDID_HERE/data/Containers/Data/Application/APPLICATION_ID_HERE/Documents/

Comment: Or you can save yourself some searching, if you know the file name, with `find . -name 'StartOfFileName*'` Man, that's buried. ;)

Answer (score 12):

You also may just go to the `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/` folder in Finder (`Shift+Cmd+G`), and then click on the `Date modified` tab on the top of the folder menu. You'll get the most recently used simulator folder without UDID.

[image]

After that, I navigate to `data/Containers/Data/Application` by hand. In the `Application` folder, grace to the `Date modified` preference chosen in Finder earlier, I also see the most recent folder on top - and there is no need to know the Application ID as well!

Answer (score 4):

Simulator files can be found by pressing ⇧+⌘+G in the finder at this path:

/Users/USER_NAME/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications

The Library folder may be hidden (to prevent non-devs from accessing it, especially on lion), but [this](http://www.macworld.com/article/1161156/view_library_folder_in_lion.html) shows you how to find it again:

Comment: Note that the up-arrow represents the Shift key.

Answer (score 1):

You can print the file location with the command in XCode Debug Console:

> p (StringPtr)getenv("HOME")

**The console will output the folder location like:**

[image]

Then navigate to this path by pressing ⇧+⌘+G in the Finder. The file should in the Documents folder.